# How to send multiple objects from GUI to Worker Thread in PySide6?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, qthread, pyside6

I want to send multiple objects from the GUI (`MainWidget`) to a Worker (`QThread`) that can perform "long" tasks, but don't know how to do this with `QTheads`.

main.py code:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from ui_widget import Ui_Form
from class1 import Test1
from class2 import Test2
from class3 import Test3

from pathlib import Path


class MainWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()
        files = Path()
        self.t1 = Test1()
        self.t1_temp = ""
        self.t2 = Test2()
        self.t2_temp = ""
        self.t3 = Test3()
        self.t3_temp = ""

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_and_run())
    
    def check_and_run(self):
        # Use checkbox to find what test to run
        if (self.test1.isChecked()):
            # Do some validation of user input...
            # If everything ok, then make class object
            self.t1 = Test1(self.test1_x.text(), self.test1_y.text())
        if (self.test2.isChecked()):
            # Do some validation of user input...
            # If everything ok, then make class object
            self.t2 = Test2(self.test2_x.text(), self.test2_y.text())
        if (self.test3.isChecked()):
            # Do some validation of user input...
            # If everything ok, then make class object
            self.t3 = Test3(self.test3_x.text(), self.test3_y.text())
        self.run_test()
# self.worker = WorkerThread()
# self.worker.start()
    def run_test(self):
        # Run the long tasks for each test if it applies
        for file in self.files:
            if (self.test1.isChecked()):
                self.t1.perform_task(self.t1_temp)
            if (self.test2.isChecked()):
                self.t2.perform_task(self.t2_temp)
            if (self.test2.isChecked()):
                self.t3.perform_task(self.t3_temp)
```

class1.py:

```py
class Test1():
    def __init__(self, x, y) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def perform_task(self):
        # Do something here...
        pass
```

From the above code, I want to run the function `run_test` inside a Worker thread.

I implemented the below `QThread` class but kept repeating myself by initializing the same variables in GUI and `QThread` which ideally I want to avoid. Any other ways to accomplish this type of behavior with the `WorkerThread`?

```py
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, t1: Test1(), t2: Test2(), t3: Test3(), t1_temp: str, 
                 t2_temp: str, t3_temp: str, files: Path, t1_flag: bool, t2_flag: bool, t3_flag: bool ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.t1 = t1
        self.t2 = t2
        self.t3 = t3
        self.t1_temp = t1_temp
        self.t2_temp = t2_temp
        self.t3_temp = t3_temp
        self.t1_flag = t1_flag
        self.t2_flag = t2_flag
        self.t3_flag = t3_flag
        self.files = files
    
    def run(self):
        for file in self.files:
            if (self.t1_flag):
                self.t1.perform_task(self.t1_temp, file)
            if (self.t2_flag):
                self.t2.perform_task(self.t2_temp)
            if (self.t3_flag):
                self.t3.perform_task(self.t3_temp)
```

Comment: your example/pseudo code is not really all that helpful.  Create a proper [mre].  Also calling the run method of a QThread defeats the purpose of the thread in the first place.  You should call `QThread.start` for it to truly be multithreaded,  It also looks like you calling callable objects in your type hints, Is that legal?

Comment: @Alexander The run method wasn't actually related to the QThread, it was coming from Class1. I have modified the above post to make this point clear by changing t1.run() to t1.perform_task(). And yes, to call a thread, I need to use QThread.start, but I want to know if there is another approach of passing multiple arguments to a WorkerThread?

Comment: Maybe just use a tuple of the objects you want to pass?

Comment: I appreciate you trying to add more details but it still isn't a [mre] and it still isn't very helpful.  If you have a bunch of objects that you need to reference in multiple classes then you can define them inside of a separate object that you can pass between both classes.  Just make sure any operations you perform are thread safe when using them in separate threads.

Comment: @sapphire Sorry but your code is invalid (you're directly calling the function, instead of referencing it in the connection) and the example not that helpful. We also already suggested in your other question that if you need to pass arguments to the thread you either use a data object (as a dictionary) or you handle them with arguments (possibly, keyworded). There is no automatic way to do this, and there is no preferred methods, there are *different* ways, each one having pros and cons, which would lead to suggestion/opinion based answers (which are off topic).